# JFileChooser click programmatically on open

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I have following code to open a JFilechooser

```
chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
String path = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
```

What I want to do is programmatically close this dialog. I see the open button, but how can I "press" it programmatically?

Comment: You need to use ActionListener for starters.

Comment: what do you mean? I know what an actionlistener is but what do you mean with "for starters"?

Comment: Well what I mean by that is you need to create an ActionListener variable and use it to detect the mouse clicking the open option.

Comment: That's the point, I don't want to click with the mouse on the button, but I want to do it automatically with for example a doClick() function

Comment: Ahhh i understand, so you click/highlight the file and it opens automatically?

Comment: No, I don't click at all, my program needs to simulate everything

Comment: [approveSelection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#approveSelection()) seems to do exactly that.

Comment: Called by the UI when the user hits the Approve button (labeled "Open" or "Save", by default)               not exactly, because the user doesn't hit the button.

Comment: One sentence more: This can also be called by the programmer.

Comment: I tried, didn't work

Comment: You will probably have to call it in another thread, because the showOpenDialog() method locks.

Comment: the `showOpenDialog` method blocks the program until the user selects something and clicks either open or cancel. Everthing afterwards doesn't get executed until the user does one of those things.

Comment: this is interesting, thanks

Comment: I'll post an answer with the thread-solution.

Comment: you deserve the credits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will simulate the user selection and opening of a file:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(YourApplication.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        chooser.setSelectedFile(new File("/your/file/path")));
        chooser.approveSelection();
    }
}).start();
chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
String path = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
```

The `Thread.sleep(100)` is ugly, but has to be in there because otherwise, the `JFileChooser` isn't open yet when `approveSelection` is called.